# What changes in the moon light (spectrum, intensity, etc...) after the spring equinox?

Tags: visible-light, astronomy, sun, moon

There must be a correlation between the earth moon system and the sun during spring, just after the spring equinox.

Comment: Why would there be a difference? The equinox refers to the earth and the sun, it does not affect the moon - unless, perhaps,  you're an astrologer ;-)

Comment: Sorry but your answer doesn't help. The moon around the earth must be somehow impacted.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is a minute change in brightness as the earth-sun distance changes from 147000 km (perihelion) to 152000 km (aphelion). Thus, at perihelion the sunlight is slightly more intense, and hence, so is the moonlight. At aphelion it's a little less intense, and at equinox it is about midway between those two. This difference is **far** smaller than the differences caused by the lunar phases.

The spectrum does not change: it's always the same sunlight reflected from the moon. The sun does not change, nor does the lunar surface. Hence there is **no** variation in the spectrum.